# Prove that if $\varphi$ is injective then $G \cong \varphi(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups and let $\varphi : G \to H$ be  a homomorphism  and  the image  of $\varphi$ , $\varphi(G)$ is a subgroup of $H$ .
Prove that if $\varphi$ is injective then  $G   \cong \varphi(G)$

My attempt:

If $\varphi$ is injective, then for every $a \in \varphi(G)$,there exist $b \in G$ such that $\varphi(b)=a$.

After that I'm not able to proceed any further.

Comment: Have you heard of the first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: Since $\varphi$ is injective, the function $\varphi|^{\varphi(G)} : G \to \varphi(G)$ given by $\varphi|^{\varphi(G)}(g) = \varphi(g)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: What does it mean to be isomorphic? It means that we have a particular homomorphism that is bijective. So you need to come up  with a homomorphism $G \rightarrow \operatorname{im}\phi$ given the information of $\phi$ and that it is injective. What function comes to mind that you can then check is bijective?

Comment: @ConnorMalin  both one-one +onto

Comment: Your attempt looks like the definition of **sur**jective rather than **in**jective

Comment: @J.W.Tanner im sorry  that  my bad thinking

Comment: yes @strawberry-sunshine

Comment: @jasmine Same! Perhaps we can work on it together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the first isomorphism theorem and the fact that $\varphi$ is injective iff $\ker\varphi$ is trivial.

Comment: Would the person who downvoted care to explain why?

Answer (score 3):

Define $f:G\to \varphi(G)$ such that $f:g\mapsto \varphi(g)$. Clearly, $f$ is surjective. We are given that $\varphi$ is injective, hence $f$ is injective. So, $f$ is a bijection. Since $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, so is $f$. Thus, $G\cong\varphi(G)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

> $$G/\ker(\phi)\cong\phi(G)$$

Comment: $\ker \phi$ is a normal subgroup of $\phi(G)$?

Comment: @azif00 Nice catch! Thank you!

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout  im not getting why u change the $G\cong \phi(G)/\ker(\phi)$ to $G/\ker(\phi)\cong\phi(G)?$  what is the difference between them ?

Comment: @azif00       got it due to normal  subgroup

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you haven't got the first homomorphism theorem at hand. Any map $f\colon X\to Y$ gives rise to a surjective (by construction) map $\tilde f\colon X\to f(X)$ defined by $\tilde f(x):=f(x)$. Therefore, your $\varphi$ gives rise to a bijective homomorphism ($=$isomorphism) $\tilde \varphi\colon G\to \varphi(G)$, meaning $G\cong\varphi(G)$.